# Prevent users from pressing "Enter" to active bootstrap button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm creating a clicker game for a school project and a big bug that comes up is users being able to click and hold down enter on a button that gives them the game's currency at an accelerated rate. I was wondering if anybody knows how to make it so the button can only be activated by holding down enter every X seconds?

**For example:**

I've held down enter on a button for 5 seconds, so the button's actions was only really activated 5 times.

**Button code** (using Bootstrap 4 if that helps)

```html
<button id="Click" onclick="AddMoney()" type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-clicker">Click!</button>
```

Answer could be in either JQuery or Javascript

Thank you so much for all the help

Comment: Search for "debouncing" as a way to rate-limit an event handler.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This prevents user from spamming enter key on a button

```js
var counter = 0;
var AddMoney = function() {
  console.log('I was clicked ' + counter + ' times');
  counter++;
}
$("#Click").keypress(function(e) {
  //Enter key
  if (e.which == 13) {
    return false;
  }
});
```

```html
<script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"
  integrity="sha256-CSXorXvZcTkaix6Yvo6HppcZGetbYMGWSFlBw8HfCJo="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<button id="Click" onclick="AddMoney()" type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-clicker">Click!</button>
```

Comment: I am unable to do this as I am currently using Jquery 3.4 and 3.4 has removed stuff like let and const

Comment: changed to jquery-3.4.1 const and let is replacement of var in new Javascript ECMA standards , should work now

Comment: Does the integrity and crossorigin stuff have anything to do with this? I currently do not have them implemented and it doesn't work. If they are required, can you explain to me what they are/what they do?

Comment: you should be able to run the code here in Stackoverflow there is a "Run code snippet" button

Comment: Short answer no, just copy the javascript

Comment: Was just tinkering around and it works without integrity or crossorigin somehow. The reason it didnt originally work was because my IDE (IntelliJ IDEA Ultimate) and or GlassFish wasn't properly refreshing/reloading the code so it kept running the old version of my code.

Thank you for your help :)